# Login to Azure SQL with JWT token in python - [SQL Server]Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>

Tags: python, azure, sqlalchemy, jwt, azure-sql-database

I try to connect to Azure SQL using SQLAlchemy in python, authenticating with JWT generated for App registration. Despite checking almost any combination of parameters and granting all potentially meaningful permissions, I still get following error:

> [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456)

I did the following:

1. Created App registration 'test-app'.
2. Executed on the db:

```
   CREATE USER [test-app] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
   EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'test-app';
   GRANT SELECT ON test_vw to [test-app];
```

3. Added 'test-app' to Contributor and Reader roles for the SQL Server.
4. Whitelisted IP in the portal - I'm able to log in through SSMS and 'AAD Universal with MFA' using personal account.
5. Generated token with (tenant ID matches the one used by the organization):

> POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/9ff8761-1be4-4729-b88df-e421e19d92f/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> client_id=[client_id]
> client_secret=[client_secret]
> scope=https://database.windows.net/.default
> grant_type=client_credentials

6. Used generated JWT token in following python code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib
import struct

server = "test-server.database.windows.net"
database = "test-db"
driver = "{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}"
jwt_token = "<jwt_token>"


SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN = 1256
exptoken = b""
for i in bytes(jwt_token, "UTF-8"):
    exptoken += bytes({i})
    exptoken += bytes(1)
tokenstruct = struct.pack("=i", len(exptoken)) + exptoken

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(
    f"Driver={driver};Server={server};Database={database};Encrypt=yes"
)
conn_str = f"mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={params}"
engine_azure = create_engine(
    conn_str,
    connect_args={"attrs_before": {SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN: tokenstruct}},
    echo=True,
)

with engine_azure.connect() as con:
    rs = con.execute("SELECT TOP 100 * FROM test_vw")
    for row in rs:
        print(row)
```

Any idea what I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

I registered an app and copied ClientID, TenantId, generated client secret and copied ClientSecret value.I created azure SQL database and copied servername, databasename in azure portal.
I tried to connect azure SQL database by using token  by replacing ClientID, TenantId, ClientSecret:
I installed SQLALchemy and adal packages using

```
pip install sqlalchemy
```

[image]

```
pip install adal
```

[image]

Connecting to Azure SQL database using below code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import adal

server = '<servername>'
database = '<databasename>'
client_id = '<ClientId>'
tenant_id = '<TenantId>'
authority_host_uri = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com'
authority_uri = authority_host_uri + '/' + tenant_id
resource_uri = 'https://database.windows.net/'
client_secret = 'NbH8Q~x8PsGqD4C~8HUGzLmql_iRS7dxOMv2Bcjj'
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority_uri)
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(resource_uri, client_id, client_secret)
conn_str = (
    'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
    f'Server={server};'
    f'Database={database};'
    'Encrypt=yes;'
    'TrustServerCertificate=yes;'
    f'AccessToken={token["accessToken"]};'
)
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(conn_str))
with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM your-table')
    for row in result:
        print(row)
```

I got below error:

[image]

I created new group and added to registered app by following below procedure:

Goto-->Azure Active directory-->Enterprise Applications

[image]

Select the app and go to--> Group/Users-->Add User/Group select the user/group and click on assign.

[image]

Set that user/group as admin of SQL server by clicking Set admin:

[image]

I tried to connect SQL database again:

[image]

It worked successfully for me kindly check from your end.

Comment: I copied first code snippet as it is, changing only URLs, client id/secret etc, what I get is:

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0)")

It seems to stem "AccessToken" part of the connection string - I can't find any documentation that would show to just put it straight in, as a parameter. I'm baffled that it works for you.

Secondly, won't your method grant admin rights to this principal? I want to limit it's privileges to SELECT on a single view.

Comment: I didn't change the URL just replace tenantid, clientid, clientSecret, servername, database. I didn't get any error related to connection string.

Comment: Sorry for not being precise - this is what I meant. I changed variables to point at my database and service principal, which translated to different DB's url.

Comment: Once check your token is valid or not?

Comment: What do you mean? Token is generated as described in the question, I also regenerated it many times through-out testing - do you see any reason for it to be invalid?